# How to count number of index or Null values in Pandas dataframe group

Tags: pandas

Its always the things that seem easy that bug me.  I am trying to get a count of the number of non-null values of some variables in a Dataframe grouped by month and year. So I can do this which works fine

```
counts_by_month=df[variable1, variable2].groupby([lambda x: x.year,lambda x: x.month]).count()
```

But I REALLY want to know is how many of those values in each group are NaNs.  So I want to count the Nans in each variable too so that I can calculate the percentage data missing in each group.  I can not find a function to do this.
or
maybe I could get to the same end by counting the total items in the group.  Then the NaNs would be Total - 'Non-Null values'

I have been trying to find out if I can somehow count the index values but I haven't been able to do so.  Any assistance on this greatly appreciated.
Best wishes
Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [279]: df
Out[279]:
     A         B         C         D         E
a  foo       NaN  1.115320 -0.528363 -0.046242
b  bar  0.991114 -1.978048 -1.204268  0.676268
c  bar  0.293008 -0.708600       NaN -0.388203
d  foo  0.408837 -0.012573  1.019361  1.774965
e  foo  0.127372       NaN       NaN       NaN

In [280]: def count_missing(frame):
    return (frame.shape[0] * frame.shape[1]) - frame.count().sum()
   .....:

In [281]: df.groupby('A').apply(count_missing)
Out[281]:
A
bar    1
foo    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the example! SHAPE gave me the information required to then calculate the NaN values. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 8):

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Faster, and doesn't need a custom function :)

Comment: `df.isnull().sum(axis=1)` is more appropriate for this question. It is counting the number of missing values in each row.

Comment: It  depends if you want the missing values per row, or per column